# Google Maps API を使った乗換検索

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps APIを使って乗換検索をしようと思い、クエリを設計しましたがうまくいきません。
公式ドキュメントもひと通り目を通したのですが、エラーがかえってくる理由を知りたいです。

クエリは
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E9%A7%85&destination=%E5%93%81%E5%B7%9D%E9%A7%85&sensor=false&mode=transit&arrival_time=1429318800
です。東京駅から品川駅への、2015年4月18日 10時00分着(JST)の乗換検索をしているつもりです。

```
import time
import datetime
import pytz
import urllib

unixtime = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 18, 10, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo')).timetuple()))
tokyo = urllib.request.quote('東京駅')  # url encoding
shina = urllib.request.quote('品川駅')  # url encoding

query = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin={orig}&destination={dest}&sensor=false&mode=transit&arrival_time={arr}".format(orig=tokyo, dest=shina, arr=unixtime)
# query : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E9%A7%85&destination=%E5%93%81%E5%B7%9D%E9%A7%85&sensor=false&mode=transit&arrival_time=1429318800'

res = urllib.request.urlopen(query)
print(res.readall())
# b'{\n   "routes" : [],\n   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"\n}\n'
```

`ZERO_RESULTS`ステータスが返ってきてしまいます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

悲しいお知らせです。
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#transit_directions_countries によると、日本では乗り換え案内がAPIから利用できないようです。

> 参考: google maps - Can't get transit directions in Japan - Stack Overflow
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909269/cant-get-transit-directions-in-japan